# Elegant way to handle from_json filter failure with default value

Tags: ansible

I'm seeking for your ideas to elegantly handle a `from_json` filter failure when it happens.

I have a generic task in an ansible role that I use to call different groovy script in sonatype nexus repository manager (the full role is [available on github](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss))

```yaml
- name: Calling Groovy script {{ script_name }}
  uri:
    url: "{{ nexus_api_scheme }}://{{ nexus_api_hostname }}:{{ nexus_api_port }}\
      {{ nexus_api_context_path }}{{ nexus_rest_api_endpoint }}/{{ script_name }}/run"
    user: 'admin'
    password: "{{ current_nexus_admin_password }}"
    headers:
      Content-Type: "text/plain"
    method: POST
    force_basic_auth: yes
    validate_certs: "{{ nexus_api_validate_certs }}"
    body: "{{ args | to_json }}"
  register: script_run
```

The scripts I call all return a json map

```json
{
"name": "name of the script",
"result": "whatever was used as a groovy return statement"
}
```

Note: there is no way to add anything else to this map from groovy, I can only push data back to ansible in the `result`

I want to use `result` to further detail if my script call leads to an error, a change or an ok status in ansible. Some groovy scripts are fully "ansible aware" and will return in `result` an escaped json string I can use to check for error/changes.
Here is a semi-fictive example:

```json
{
"name": "create_repos_from_list",
"result": "{\"changed\": false, \"error\": false, \"action_details\": [{\"name\": \"my_registry\", \"format\": \"docker\", \"type\": \"hosted\", \"status\": \"no change\"}]}" 
}
```

But (for time being...) some other scripts are not "ansible aware" (or I cannot change them myself) and will return in `result` a simple string (without any usable information in most cases).

Now my real problem: If I get a json result I want to use it to check for failure or change. If its not a json result, I'll just rely on the http 200 for a success (until the script can be fixed).

I was almost there with the following options to my task:

```yaml
  failed_when: >-
    script_run.status != 200
    or
    (script_run.json.result | from_json | default({})).error | default(false) | bool
  changed_when: >-
    (script_run.json.result | from_json | default({})).changed | default(false) | bool
```

Unfortunately, when `result` is a simple string, `from_json` will fire an error (`Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`) before the default can be applied and my playbook ends there.

My current workaround is to add another condition to check if `result` starts with a `{` before trying to read json but I'm not really happy with this (as the json string might still be corrupted and still lead to an error)

If any of you have experience/idea on how to gracefully handle this json decode error with a default value or to nicelly check if a string can be decoded as json in ansible, I'll take all suggestions.

Comment: i found out that writing complex stuff in `failed_when`/`changed_when` can get easily out of hand. Have you tried creating a filter and then do something like `failed_when: script_run | my_role_failed` ? https://gist.github.com/tuxfight3r/37048ba536575277f5f4d26813d69489

Comment: I actually can't understand why I didn't think of this earlier !!! :) I just have to make sure this will be compatible with distributing the role as it is public. Thanks for giving me some more work and tests ;)

Comment: filters live inside your ansible role, under `filter_plugins/`, so distribution shouldnt be an issue. You can go as far as creating empty ansible roles that only define filters and then include them in other roles (through `meta/main.yml`) to be used there.

Comment: @user2599522 please do consider posting that as an "answer", and I hope that Olivier accepts it because that is a **fantastic** answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that writing complex stuff in `failed_when`/`changed_when` can get easily out of hand. Have you tried creating a filter and then do something like `failed_when: script_run | my_role_failed` ?

https://gist.github.com/tuxfight3r/37048ba536575277f5f4d26813d69489

filters live inside your ansible role, under `filter_plugins/`, so distribution shouldnt be an issue. You can go as far as creating empty ansible roles that only define filters and then include them in other roles (through `meta/main.yml`) to be used there.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know (very late...), that this has lead to a [successful implementation working totally as expected](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/filter_plugins/nexus3_oss_filters.py)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it meets the "elegant" threshold, but I used a custom test plugin, and a jinja2 `{{ <something> if <test> else <somethingelse> }}` expression to solve this problem:

```py
# test_plugins/is_json.py

import json

def is_json(input_string):
    ''' Tests if input_string is valid JSON
        Returns a bool
    '''
    try:
        json.loads(input_string)
        return True
    except:
        return False

class TestModule(object):
    def tests(self):
        return {
            'json': is_json,
        }
```

```yaml
# test_json_test.yaml
---
- name: 'Test json test'
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: 'Give us an empty dict on invalid json'
      with_items:
        - ' {"somekey": "somevalue"} ' # valid JSON
        #  ^-extra space here to ensure Ansible treats this as a string
        - '{"somekey": "somevalue"}' # valid JSON
        - ' {     }' # valid
        - ' [     ]' # valid
        - '[]' # valid
        - "I'm not valid JSON" # invalid JSON
      debug:
        msg: '{{ item if item is json else "{}" }}'
        #                        ^^^^-our test
```

Output:

```
PLAY [Test json test] *************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Give us an empty dict on invalid json] ************
ok: [localhost] => (item= {"somekey": "somevalue"} ) => {
    "msg": " {\"somekey\": \"somevalue\"} "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'somekey': 'somevalue'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "somekey": "somevalue"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item= {     }) => {
    "msg": " {     }"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item= [     ]) => {
    "msg": " [     ]"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[]) => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=I'm not valid JSON) => {
    "msg": {}
}

PLAY RECAP ****************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks. This is still much more verbose in the playbook than with the custom filter I developed based on the accepted answer. Quick and easy though, I'll keep it in mind for possible future problems.