# Ansible: Loop over dict and filetree

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How to loop over dict and filetree? I want to recursively template files with .j2 suffix (key) to destination location (value), also basename should be renamed (remove .j2 suffix). Its a perfect use case. Unfortunatelly ansible is not good with complex data structures.

Input:

```
vars:
  applications:
    application1:
      svcpaths:
        localfolder/bardir1: remotefolder/bardir1
        localfolder/bardir2: remotefolder/bardir2
        localfolder/bardir3: remotefolder/bardir3
    application2:
      svcpaths:
        localfolder/bardir5: remotefolder/bardir5
        localfolder/bardir6: remotefolder/bardir6
```

My try:

```
    - name: Files to template
      template:
        src: "{{ item.src }}"
        dest: "{{ item.destination }}/{{ item.name | regex_replace('.j2','') }}"
      loop: |
        [
        {% for c in applications %}
        {% if applications[c]['svcpaths'] is defined and applications[c]['svcpaths'] |list|length >0  %}
        {% for o,m in applications[c]['svcpaths'].items() %}
        {% for i in lookup('filetree', o ) %}
        {% if i.state == 'file' and i.path | regex_search('.\.j2') %}
        {
        "name": "{{ i.path }}",
        "src": "{{ i.src }}",
        "destination": "{{ m }}"
        }, 
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        ]
```

I know that using jinja in plays is not good and I want to avoid it, if its possible. Also input datastructure should not be changed.

Thannks

Comment: I will simply point you to [a question I asked a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384113/elegant-way-to-handle-from-json-filter-failure-with-default-value) which in appearance has nothing to do with your current problem. Meanwhile, my advice is the same as the one I got and which saved my day: It's time to write your custom filter, or lookup plugin or module... anything that will let you do the hard part directly in python.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think there is a reasonably simple solution.  If you write a task file like this called `template_files.yml`:

```
---
- name: render templates to dest_dir
  loop: "{{ query('filetree', src_dir) }}"

  # we need this to avoid conflicts with the "item" variable in
  # the calling playbook.
  loop_control:
    loop_var: template
  when: template.src.endswith('.j2')
  template:
    src: "{{ template.src }}"
    dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ (template.src|basename)[:-3] }}"
```

Then you can write a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    applications:
      application1:
        svcpaths:
          localfolder/bardir1: /tmp/remotefolder/bardir1
          localfolder/bardir2: /tmp/remotefolder/bardir2
          localfolder/bardir3: /tmp/remotefolder/bardir3
      application2:
        svcpaths:
          localfolder/bardir5: /tmp/remotefolder/bardir5
          localfolder/bardir6: /tmp/remotefolder/bardir6

  tasks:
    # generate a list of {key: src, value: destination} 
    # dictionaries from your data structure.
    - set_fact:
        templates: "{{ templates|default([]) + item|dict2items }}"
      loop: "{{ applications|json_query('*.svcpaths')}}"

    # show what the generated variable looks like
    - debug:
        var: templates

    # template all the things
    - include_tasks: template_files.yml
      loop: "{{ templates }}"
      vars:
        src_dir: "{{ item.key }}"
        dest_dir: "{{ item.value }}"
```

Given that I have a set of local files that look like this:

```
localfolder/bardir1/example.txt.j2
localfolder/bardir2/example.txt.j2
localfolder/bardir3/example.txt.j2
localfolder/bardir5/example.txt.j2
localfolder/bardir6/example.txt.j2
```

Running the playbook results in:

```
/tmp/remotefolder/bardir6/example.txt
/tmp/remotefolder/bardir5/example.txt
/tmp/remotefolder/bardir3/example.txt
/tmp/remotefolder/bardir2/example.txt
/tmp/remotefolder/bardir1/example.txt
```

I think that's probably easier to read and understand than the Jinja-template based solution you're using.

Comment: I need nesed loop over subnested loop (loop over application1 and its svcpaths, etc)
So fist loop it will be -> `application1 localfolder/bardir1 /tmp/remotefolder/bardir1 `in case if `"{{ item.key }} {{ item.value.key }} {{ item.value.value }}"`. Second loop will be `application1 localfolder/bardir2 /tmp/remotefolder/bardir3` Third loop `application1 localfolder/bardir3 /tmp/remotefolder/bardir3` .... and so on ... untill another loop  `application2 localfolder/bardir5 /tmp/remotefolder/bardir5` ,etc...